# python Fetch records from SQL Server using arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

Python code which was working fine when a single integer is given for replacing `?` but throws me below error while using array

> File "opsStudentLookup.py", line 231, in upsOps
>       WHERE TRU.intUserId IN ? ''',rmSet)
>   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=set', 'HY105')

```
import pyodbc
rmSet = [167369, 36006]
sqlConnect = pyodbc.connect(sqlConStr)
sqlCur = sqlConnect.cursor()
   sqlCur.execute('''SELECT M.fldUserId ,TRU.intRuleGroupId ,TRM.strRuleGroupName
        FROM USER_MASTER M
        LEFT JOIN GROUP_USER TRU ON M.fldUserId = TRU.intUserId
        LEFT JOIN GROUP_MASTER TRM ON TRU.intRuleGroupId = TRM.intRuleGroupID
                        WHERE TRU.intUserId IN ? ''',rmSet)
```

Can someone let me know where am I going wrong? 
From the error it seems I should not be using `arrays`, if yes what should be used because **using `set()` data also throws similar type of error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `?` in your query can only represent a *single* value.  If you have 2 values, you need 2 `?`s.

```
sqlCur.execute('''SELECT ...
    WHERE TRU.intUserId IN (?, ?) ''', rmSet)
```

If the number of values in `rmSet` will change, then you'll need to dynamically add the `?`s to the query:

```
vars = ','.join(['?'] * len(rmSet))

sqlCur.execute('''SELECT ...
    WHERE TRU.intUserId IN ({0})'''.format(vars), rmSet)
```

Comment: number of elements in list changes for every execution.

Comment: Then you'll need to dynamically add the `?`s into the query.  `vars = ','.join(['?'] * len(rmSet))` then  `sqlCur.execute('''SELECT ... WHERE TRU.intUserID IN (%s)''' % vars, rmSet)`

Comment: WHERE TRU.intUserId IN %s ''' %vars ,rmSet)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: That was a typo on my end, `WHERE TRU.intUserId IN %s` should be `WHERE TRU.intUserId IN (%s)`, I forgot the parenthesis!

Comment: these are changes, I made   vars = ','.join(['?']*len(rmSet))
   print(vars)
   sqlCur.execute('''SELECT M.fldUserId ,TRU.intRuleGroupId ,TRM.strRuleGroupName
        FROM USER_MASTER M
        LEFT JOIN GROUP_USER TRU ON M.fldUserId = TRU.intUserId
        LEFT JOIN GROUP_MASTER TRM ON TRU.intRuleGroupId = TRM.intRuleGroupID
                        WHERE TRU.intUserId IN (%s) ''' % vars ,rmSet)
?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opsStudentLookup.py", line 350, in <module>
    upsOps()
TypeError: execute() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: I get the previous error without brackets `()` or the recent 0 arguments error with given with `()`.
I using python 2.7.12

Comment: Try `'''SELECT ... WHERE TRU.intUserID IN ({0})'''.format(vars)` instead?  I'm still learning Python myself, so I'm not 100% sure what's wrong.  I wonder if *both* `vars` and `rmSet` were being consumed by the `%` operator.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for the help.
I get this error with new suggestion.
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Does `print('''SELECT ... WHERE TRU.intUserId IN ({0})'''.format(vars))` look correct?  I normally use MySQL, not MSSQL, so maybe there are some syntax differences.

Comment: looks correct, this execution has only one userid hence only one `?`
 SELECT M.fldUserId ,TRU.intRuleGroupId ,TRM.strRuleGroupName
        FROM USER_MASTER M
        LEFT JOIN GROUP_USER TRU ON M.fldUserId = TRU.intUserId
        LEFT JOIN GROUP_MASTER TRM ON TRU.intRuleGroupId = TRM.intRuleGroupID
                        WHERE TRU.intUserId IN (?)

Comment: My bad, it was failing for another typo in the program. My apologies again.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)